# regex to match s3 urls in nginx location directive & proxy to amazon s3

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, amazon-s3

In nginx location directive, how do I match s3 urls.

for example, the wrong url is:

```
http://example.com/https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/logo.jpg?1404251306
```

from Logs, I can see nginx can that it able to service the request from this url & returns a 404.

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [15/Aug/2014:12:38:04 +0000] "GET /https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 151 "-" "Mo
```

with this, I want to match this url, proxy the request to s3 & return `logo.jpg`. I have come up with something like this:

```
location ~* ^/https/(.*) {
  set $s3_host 's3.amazonaws.com';
  set $s3_bucket 'mybucket';

  proxy_set_header       Host $s3_host;
  proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
  proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
  proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
  proxy_ignore_headers   "Set-Cookie";
  proxy_buffering        off;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  resolver               8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout       10s;

  proxy_pass http://$1;
}
```

**Questions**:

1. What regex should I use in location directive so it matches amazon
   s3 urls ONLY.
2. Currently, it handles any bucket. How do I restrict
       the bucket as well?

### [Update]

I get the following error:

```
==> /var/log/nginx/error.log <==
2014/08/15 13:53:08 [error] 1579#0: *1 invalid port in upstream ":/s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/logo.jpg", client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET /https://s3.amazonaws.com//mybucket/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "54.164.92.206"
```

Comment: You should fix your links instead of trying to mitigate the symptoms of the problem.

Comment: already done. but there are few older clients(desktop app users who haven't upgraded to latest version) who are still using the older URLs. this is done to give them a migration path.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: (1) Sorry, some typo here (2) I adjust regex so it matches one or more slash before string `mybucket` like your log above.**

Well, maybe you mean something like this

```
location ~* ^/https://s3\.amazonaws\.com/+mybucket(.*) {
  ...
  proxy_pass http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket$1;
}
```

Comment: with this, I get `invalid port in upstream` error.

Comment: @CuriousMind, check the updated answer

Comment: This doesn't match the location, I get `404`

Comment: I recently tested above configuration and it's working as expected. No 404 error or other nginx error messages. Probably you should reorder the location. In my case, the location direction was right below `location / {`. If reordering location doesn't help, please add the full version of your nginx config in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this error and it was because I was setting the `Host` header wrong.

Here's the config that ended up working:

```
set $s3_bucket        's3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com';
...
proxy_set_header       Host $s3_bucket;
```

Note that the host header does **not** include http/https. That should be included in the `proxy_pass` line

```
      proxy_pass             http://$s3_bucket/whatever
```